# Consistency strategy for two datacenters

Tags: cassandra

What is the best write/read strategy that is fault tolerant and fast for reads when all nodes are up?

I have 2 replicas in each datacenter and at first I was considering using QUORUM for writes and LOCAL_QUORUM for reads but reads would fail if one node crashes.

The other strategy that I came up with is to use QUORUM for writes and TWO for reads. It should work fast in normal conditions (because we will get results from the nearest nodes first) and it will work slower when any node crashes.

1. Is this a situation where it is recommended to use consistency level TWO or it is for some other purpose?
2. When would you use CL THREE?
3. Do you have a better strategy for consistent and fault tolerant writes/reads?

Comment: Is there any impediment to avoid using ONE for read?

Comment: Yes, in this case i need consistency that i cannot acomplish if I use ONE (unless I use ALL for writes which is not Fault tolerant).

Comment: Ideally I would like to have something like EACH_ONCE for write and TWO for reads so the system would be fault tolerant even if 2 nodes dies (one in each datacenter).

Answer (score 2):

You first have to chose if you want consistency or availability.  If you chose consistency, then you need to have R + W > N, where R is how many nodes you read from, W is how many nodes you write to, and N is the number of replicas.

Then you have to chose if you want reads/writes to always span multiple data centers.

Once you make those choices, you can then chose you consistency level (or it will be dictated to you).

If, for example, you decide you need consistency, and you don't want writes/reads to span multiple data centers, then you can read at LOCAL_QUORUM (which is 2 in your case) and write at ONE, or vice versa.

2 copies per dc is an odd choice.  Typically you want to do LOCAL_QUORUM, with 3 replicas in each data center.  That lets you read and write only using nodes within a datacenter, but allows 1 node to go down.

Comment: Well we don't need consistency and availability in the same time. We also need replicas in both dc so that we can change read/write consistency if one dc goes down. In that case we are fine with losing consistency for availability. But in normal circumstances we would like to be consistent and fault tolerant for a single node crash.

Comment: @sbridges's note about having less than three replicas in each DC is key.  One you have three in each DC, you can have very nice locally strong consistency and still tolerate the failure of one local node. Changing consistency levels when nodes go down is generally a bad idea; you might as well use the reduced consistency level all of the time since you're willing to accept that level of consistency and the behavior will be the same when nodes are up. Consistency levels are also pluggable, so you can create EACH_ONE if you want to.

Comment: I cannot split keys by datacenter because I need availability when one datacenter goes down. So in this case it wont work if I use LOCAL_QUORUM for both read and writes. Also I cannot use the reduced consistency level all the time. It would be the same only in split brain case but not if dc goes down.